# Explain package-lock.json and if mine will cause a problem

Tags: node.js, npm, visual-studio-code, npm-package

I just cloned our remote repo on my new system that I just installed Node/npm on. Then I ran `npm install` to get all the packages installed. Was this not the right command?

VSCode is showing me huge differences in the lock file. The lockFileVersion changed from 1 to 2 and there many, perhaps hundreds, of changes in this huge file. Why would that happen and what is the potential impact of checking this in?

It looks like the changes are mostly related to node modules. example:

```
"node_modules/css-declaration-sorter/node_modules/chalk/node_modules/supports-color": {}
```

Where that entry wasn't there in the existing repo.

Or am I making a big deal out of nothing?

Answer (score 1):

Your package.json file specifies limits and ranges of acceptable versions, while the lock file specifies the exact versions you are using, taking into account all the dependency resolutions that were available the last time you ran `install`.

In general, if your code builds and runs, you want to publish the lock file to your repository.  This will ensure the production build will use the exact versions you have built with.